# What's the easiest way to fetch a SharePoint file by a path from the Microsoft Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Say you have a file path like: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/MyDocLib/Folder/Foo.docx`

What's the easiest way to turn this into a Microsoft Graph call to fetch the contents of the file which I assume we need to do via the `drives` endpoint using the correct id's.

I assume I might have to run multiple calls and perhaps assume that /slash1/slash2 is the site, then the next is the doclib etc(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure is it the easiest or the only option but the below solution demonstrates how to
meet the requirements of [Addressing resources in OneDrive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems):

- first step would be *to transform the URL into a sharing token (see below section)*, for that matter we utilize [`Shares` API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get)
- once the *sharing token* is generated, the OneDrive API request to download a file could be constructed like this: `/shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}/driveitem/content`

**How to transform the URL into a sharing token**

For url:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/MyDocLib/Folder/Foo.docx
```

should be generated the following token:

```
u!aHR0cHM6Ly9jb250b3NvLnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tL3NpdGVzL3NvbWVzaXRlL015RG9jTGliL0ZvbGRlci9Gb28uZG9jeA
```

On how to encode a URL is described in [MS Graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get) (C# version is provided there)

NodeJS version:

```
function urlToToSharingToken(url) {
    var trimEnd = function(str, c) {
        c = c ? c : ' ';
        var i = str.length - 1;
        for (; i >= 0 && str.charAt(i) == c; i--);
        return str.substring(0, i + 1);
    };
    var value = Buffer.from(url).toString('base64');
    return "u!" + trimEnd(value, '=').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');
}
```

**Example**

The example demonstrates how download a file by url provided in the `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/MyDocLib/Folder/Foo.docx` format using [`msgraph-sdk-javascript` library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript):

```
    const sharedItemId = urlToToSharingToken(url);  //1.construct sharing token
    const requestUrl = "/shares/" + sharedItemId + "/driveitem/content";  //2. construct a query to download a file content

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var builder = client.api(requestUrl);
        getAsBinary(builder, (err, stream) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(stream);
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's a pretty nifty solution indeed - and thanks for the pointer on creating the sharing encoded part. Much better than first getting the drive and then the item based on paths :)